# fsockopen(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in codeigniter email send

Tags: php, smtp, codeigniter-3

Getting error while sending email in my codeigniter project from live ubuntu 16.04 server. **(On localhost it works fine.)**

My smtp configuration is:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'email@email.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => 'password', // change it to yours
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

It's work fine on my local server. but when I host it on live server I got the error. How do I solve this error? Please help.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): SSL: Connection reset by peer
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1990
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/libraries/SendEmail.php
>   Line: 26 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 207 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1990
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/libraries/SendEmail.php
>   Line: 26 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 207 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unknown error)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1990
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/libraries/SendEmail.php
>   Line: 26 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 207 Function: send
>
> File: /var/www/project/company/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error yesterday. The Error caused by SSL which has a problem on the server. So, I changed the SSL method to TLS to avoid the problem SSL. Configure your config with these rules.

```
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "*your@email.com*";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "*yourpassword*";
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = "4";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = "tls"; // This is an important part of changing  to TLS
    $config['validate'] = TRUE;
```

It's Works for me, Email is sent via TLS protocol. Maybe this is not the best solution for security.